# Affinity between a text and a list of keywords?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a portion of text (500-1500 chars)

And I have a list of keywords (1000 records)..

What should I do to find the keywords from that list that are related to my given text?

I was thinking to search the occorences of those keywords in my text for every keywords in the list, but it's a bit "expensive" i think

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to tell us where the words are stored. mySQL, Text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I throw my hat in the ring …

```
function extractWords($text, $minWordLength = null, array $stopwords = array(), $caseIgnore = true)
{
    $pattern = '/\w'. (is_null($minWordLength) ? '+' : '{'.$minWordLength.',}') .'/';
    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);
    $words = $matches[0];

    if ($caseIgnore) {
        $words = array_map('strtolower', $words);
        $stopWords = array_map('strtolower', $stopwords);
    }

    $words = array_diff($words, $stopwords);

    return $words;
}

function countKeywords(array $words, array $keywords, $threshold = null, $caseIgnore = true) 
{   
    if ($caseIgnore) {
        $keywords = array_map('strtolower', $keywords);
    }

    $words = array_intersect($words, $keywords);
    $counts = array_count_values($words);
    arsort($counts, SORT_NUMERIC);

    if (!is_null($threshold)) {
        $counts = array_filter($counts, function ($count) use ($threshold) { return $count >= $threshold; });
    }

    return $counts;
}
```

Usage:

```
$text = 'a b c a';  // your text
$keywords = array('a', 'b');  // keywords from your database

$words = extractWords($text);
$count = countKeywords($words, $keywords);
print_r($count);

$total = array_sum($count);
var_dump($total);

$affinity = ($total == 0 ? 0 : 1 / (count($words) / $total));
var_dump($affinity);
```

Prints

> Array
>   (
>       [a] => 2
>       [b] => 1
>   )
>   int(3)
>   float(0.75)

Answer (score 2):

If the keywords always stay the same you could create an index over them which improves search speed (tremendously). The standard data structure to handle this is the [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) but a much better (!) alternative is the [Aho-Corasick automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) or another multi-pattern search algorithm such as multi-pattern Horspool (also known as Wu-Manber algorithm).

Finally, a very simple alternative is to concatenate all your keywords with pipes (`|`) and use the result as a regular expression. Technically, this approaches the Aho-Corasick automaton and is much simpler for you to implement.