# paragraph comparison in PHP

Tags: php, text

i was wondering... let's say i have a webpage that crawls articles from the web. all i get is the title and the article in plain-text. is there a PHP script or webservice that can relate articles between them? or... is there a PHP script that can generate keywords from a paragraph?

i have tested a script in JAVA that works, but maybe there's a PHPclass somewhere that can help...

thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful to get some more information on that Java code. Also can you clarify what kind of relation you are looking for? Or are you just looking for keyword density?

Comment: i don't have the code in JAVA, i just remember i used it once a long time ago, and about the relation i mean like a numerical value of how alike is one text to another. keyword density would be really useful in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680544/affinity-between-a-text-and-a-list-of-keywords/4682121#4682121) can be used to extract words from text and compare them against each other. Rough example:

```
// For better results grab the texts manually and paste them here.
$nyt = file_get_contents('http://www.nytimes.com/2011/01/19/technology/19apple.html?pagewanted=print');
$sfc = file_get_contents('http://www.sfgate.com/cgi-bin/article.cgi?f=/c/a/2011/01/19/BUAK1HARUL.DTL&type=business');

$nyt = strip_tags($nyt);
$sfc = strip_tags($sfc);

// stopwords from english snowball porter stemmer
$stopwordsFile = dirname(__FILE__).'/includes/stopwords_en.txt';
if (file_exists($stopwordsFile)) {
    $stopwords = file($stopwordsFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
} else {
    $stopwords = array();
}

$nytWords = extractWords($nyt, 3, $stopwords);
$sfcWords = extractWords($sfc, 3, $stopwords);

$nyt2sfcCount = countKeywords($nytWords, $sfcWords, 4);
$sfc2nytCount = countKeywords($sfcWords, $nytWords, 4);

// absolute
print_r($nyt2sfcCount);
print_r($sfc2nytCount);

$nyt2sfcFactor = strlen($sfc) / strlen($nyt);
$sfc2nytFactor = strlen($nyt) / strlen($sfc);

print($nyt2sfcFactor . PHP_EOL);
print($sfc2nytFactor . PHP_EOL);

foreach ($nyt2sfcCount as $word => $count) {
    $nyt2sfcCountRel[$word] = $count * $nyt2sfcFactor;
}

foreach ($sfc2nytCount as $word => $count) {
    $sfc2nytCountRel[$word] = $count * $sfc2nytFactor;
}

// relative
print_r($nyt2sfcCountRel);
print_r($sfc2nytCount);
print_r($nyt2sfcCount);
print_r($sfc2nytCountRel);

// reduce
$nyt2sfcCountRed = array_intersect_key($nyt2sfcCount, $sfc2nytCount);
$sfc2nytCountRed = array_intersect_key($sfc2nytCount, $nyt2sfcCount);

// reduced absolute
print_r($nyt2sfcCountRed);
print_r($sfc2nytCountRed);

foreach ($nyt2sfcCountRed as $word => $count) {
    $nyt2sfcCountRedRel[$word] = $count * $nyt2sfcFactor;
}

foreach ($sfc2nytCountRed as $word => $count) {
    $sfc2nytCountRedRel[$word] = $count * $sfc2nytFactor;
}

// reduced relative
print_r($nyt2sfcCountRedRel);
print_r($sfc2nytCountRed);
print_r($nyt2sfcCountRed);
print_r($sfc2nytCountRedRel);
```

Comment: thanks man, really useful, from your example i'll have to use a dictionary to cut common words like "the", "and", "for", etc. anyways it's a cool start, and thanks for the time!

Comment: I put my includes/stopwords_en.txt on http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=9AB2thTp. It's a compiled version of http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/english/stemmer.html. You can find stopwords for other languages there too.